# RxJava How to subscribe a Subject to an Observable

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

The documentation says, that a Subject is a Observer and can subscribe to Observables, but I can't find a way to do it in code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#subscribe(rx.Observer)

Comment: just use the `Subject` object as the param for `Observable#subscribe`

Comment: The problem was, that I was using an Observable<Void>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sample junit code:

```
@Test
public void shouldSubscribeToSubjectToObservable() throws InterruptedException {
    Observable<Integer> observable = Observable.just(1, 2);
    PublishSubject<Object> subject = PublishSubject.create();
    subject.subscribe(o -> {
        System.out.println("o = " + o);
    });

    observable.subscribe(subject);

    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```